# how to do a unix find based on size of files, including in subdirectories?

Tags: macos, unix, directory, find, grep

Trying to use osx find to find all the files in my directory tree.  I googled and SO'd and looked at man but none helped.

So far I have: `find -f -c1mb`  which is clearly wrong.

Comment: r u trying to find a particular file?

Comment: no, just all files that are larger than a certain size, say 20k

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/linux/how-to-find-large-file-size-on-linux-solution/

Comment: Aziz that didn't really work on osx as it didn't give me filename that I could use to delete them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -size +20000
```

The above one should work.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to find files bigger than 1 Mb, then do

```
$ find . -size +1M
```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, this works:

```
find . -type f -size +10k
```

The above would find all files in the current directory and below, being at least 10k.

Comment: perfect.  Worked on my mac great.  would like to be able to use mb and gb but couldn't get the format right so just using large k figures for now.  Thanks!

Comment: I've +1'd but I'm actually gonna accept Venk's answer as it was shorter.  Thanks for help though!

Comment: Sure thing - glad you got the answer you needed and of course thanks for +1! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This command tell you "the size" too :-)

```
find . -size +1000k -exec du -h {} \;
```